# How can I close a specific Program in Win11 after timeout with cmd?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

I recently got to know about the command

`shutdown /s -t (time in second)`

which let me shutdown my desktop after the specified time. I was wondering, Can I close a program like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shutdown command will shutdown, reboot, suspend or log off the computer and cannot be used to control programs individually.

The timeout setting is specifically created for the Shutdown command.

You can kill programs using taskkill, but it does not have a timeout setting.
It is possible to use 2 commands, a ping localhost -n x which pings your own computer x times a second and after that close the program.

An example of such line would be:

```
ping localhost -n 300 && taskkill /IM cmd.exe
```